# Sending a transaction with minimum gas; will it ever complete?

Tags: erc-20, gas, gas-price

About one day ago I sent a transaction with an average gas limit, but a set a price of 15 Gwei. The transaction is still pending nearly 24 hours later and is still pending; will it ever complete?

Answer (score 1):

If the average gas price and the transaction flux stay as high as it is since a few months, it is very unlikely.
If you want to replace your transaction you can send a new transaction with the same nonce and a gas price much higher.

Comment: Yeap this method is known as replace-by-fee

Answer (score 0):

As the question is "will it ever" the answer is most likely "yes". 15 GWei is not a bad fee in general, we just currently happen to be in a situation where that is not acceptable. Sometimes transactions with even 0 gas price are mined (although the reasons for that remain a bit unclear).

So, as you were already told, just wait or replace the transaction.